# Horizontal Scalability in python-tornado

Tags: python, server, fork, tornado, horizontal-scaling

I am new in tornado and I want to make web application with tornado and want to scale one instance of tornado application to many in separated servers.
I want to have a redirector application and it fork processes in servers and redirector application manage requests from clients and pass request to server that have minimum process.
please tell me how can I do it in the best way.
thank you for helping me.

Comment: Did you try doing anything? Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: yes I saw [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-optimizepythoncloud2/) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8637366/the-proper-way-to-scale-python-tornado-application) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13941903/when-to-use-tornado-when-to-use-twisted-cyclone-gevent-other) but I am looking for the best solution.